# Excel VBA extract InnerText after <a> tag

Tags: excel, vba, innertext

I am trying to extract some InnerText after a  tag.

This is the HTML:

```
'<pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="view_10496.html">view_10496.html</a>     06-Feb-2021 01:54     60K
<a href="view_10498.html">view_10498.html</a>     06-Feb-2021 01:54     53K
<a href="view_10499.html">view_10499.html</a>     06-Feb-2021 01:54     26K
<a href="view_10500.html">view_10500.html</a>     06-Feb-2021 01:54     15K
<a href="view_10501.html">view_10501.html</a>     06-Feb-2021 01:54    128K
```

My code can pick up the content of the a tag but I also want to extract the text behind the a tag.
The counter makes sure that I discard the first a tag.

```
Set alle_a_tags = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each a_tag In alle_a_tags
    
    If teller = 0 Then
        GoTo Volgende_a_tag
    End If

    InnerHTML = a_tag.InnerHTML
    InnerText = a_tag.InnerText
    Href = a_tag.Href
    Date = ...
Next
```

Comment: Please post your full VBA code. The shown part seems to be not optimal. I think you want the `innerText` of the second a tag `<a href="view_10498.html">view_10498.html</a>` You can use `getElementsByTagName()` to generate a node collection of all a tags in the HTML document. It's always a good idea to cut out a part of the HTML document with only the a tags you want. If the shown a tags are all or the first ones in den HTML document you can get the `innerText` of the second a tag with `ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(1).innertext` If you need more explanation please post VBA code and URL

Comment: Ok, now seen. You want the date right? The HTML is not good formatet. But I think the date is the `nextSibling` node of the a tag. `ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(1).nextSibling.innertext` Remember, that works only if the a tags are the only or the first ones of the part of the HTML structure. To understand what you are doing search for informations about the DOM (Document Object Model). The most you will find are infos for JavaScript. But that doesn't matter. The rules are always the same. If you post your VBA and HTML (better the URL) I can explain more.

Comment: Hi Zwenn. The url itself is an url from a intranet-system so that won't work for you. What I want is to extract the text behind each <a> tag. So the date and time etc. In the DOM this is between brackets like "        06-Feb-2021  01:54     60K      ".

Comment: I think @Zwenn is likely right about nextSibling but would help if you gave us larger html segment. Whether you use .innerText depends on nodeType of nextSibling element.

Comment: I hope this is clear. The <pre> tag one <a> tag that is not interesting and than a lot of <a> tags and on the next line between "  " the date and time. That part is what I am hoping to extract within the loop.
<h1>
<hr>
<pre>
   <a href="../"</a>
   <a href="view_10496.html">view_10496.html</a>
   "                 06-Feb-2021  01:54    60K
   "
   <a href="view_10498.html">view_10498.html</a>
   "                06-Feb-2021  01:54    60K
   "
   <a href="view_10499.html">view_10499.html</a>
   "                06-Feb-2021  01:54    60K
   "

Comment: Yes, a larger HTML segment would help. @QHarr Thanks for `Whether you use .innerText depends on nodeType of nextSibling element.` It's a longer time ago since I had used pure text nodes and I'am not sure anymore about how to get the text.

Comment: Just tried this line of code:  Date = a_tag.nextSibling.InnerText but that triggers an error 438 Property or method not supported by this object (error translated into English).

Comment: Try the code from QHaars answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based only on HTML provided:

You can match the substring of the href attribute value with starts with operator to get right preceding nodes. You then need to move to the NextSibling to get desired text. You can use Select Case to determine which property to access depending on nodeType of that sibling

```
Dim i As Long, nodes As Object, nextSibling As Object

Set nodes = ie.document.querySelectorAll("[href^='view_']")

For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
    Set nextSibling = nodes.Item(i).nextSibling
    'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType
    Select Case nextSibling.NodeType
    Case 1
        Debug.Print nextSibling.innerText
    Case 3
        Debug.Print nextSibling.NodeValue
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the text behind closing tags using a regular expression.

example: (?<=</a>)(.|\r).*?$

RegEx-Sandbox: **https://regex101.com/**

Comment: Hi Dolek. I suppose you mean how to extract the date out of the entire text. That however is not the issue. The issue is to extract the entire string itself at first. Getting the date out of that string is something I think I can do myself.

Comment: it extracts the entire string behind the tag, not only the date. Copy the HTML code to the sandbox and test the regex

Comment: Ok thanks dolek. I will have to do some reading about regex. I used a regex once many years ago. Just to be sure. I can use the regex within the loop ?

Comment: Yes, but not bulletproof. It would require that the structure of HTML is always the same. 

have a look at https://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/

regex.Execute returns a set of the matches. You can iterate over them within your loop

Comment: Thank you for the links to the RegEx sanbox and the page with Excel RegEx tutorial dolek.